# Joining SAAJ and JAXB

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, saaj

I'm creating a web service withoug axis. I'm using SAAJ, JAXB and Servlet. I can marshall and unmarshall a class with JAXB correctly. But how can I use together SAAJ and JAXB for SOAP communication. I want put the JAXB converted xml text to SOAP BODY tag with SAAJ. How can I do this? I read SAAJ documents that's on the Oracle site but it isn't understandable. They tell so complex.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could do the following:

**Demo**

`SOAPBody` implements `org.w3c.dom.Node` so you can have your JAXB implementation marshal to it:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
        SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("Hello World");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(foo, body);

        message.saveChanges();
        message.writeTo(System.out);
    }

}
```

**Java Model (Foo)**

Below is a simple Java model we will use for this example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code (I have formatted it in my answer to make it easier to read).

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <foo>
            <bar>Hello World</bar>
        </foo>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Below is an example using JAXB with the JAX-WS APIs (for details on service see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/02/leveraging-moxy-in-your-web-service-via.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Dispatch;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import blog.jaxws.provider.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        QName serviceName = new QName("http://service.jaxws.blog/", "FindCustomerService");
        Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
        QName portQName = new QName("http://example.org", "SimplePort");
        service.addPort(portQName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, "http://localhost:8080/Provider/FindCustomerService?wsdl");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FindCustomerRequest.class, FindCustomerResponse.class);
        Dispatch<Object> sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, jc, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
        FindCustomerRequest request = new FindCustomerRequest();
        FindCustomerResponse response = (FindCustomerResponse) sourceDispatch.invoke(request);
        System.out.println(response.getValue().getFirstName());
    }

}
```

Comment: that's very great answer. So I found an another api that name is jax-ws. which way better? SAAJ & JAXP or jax-ws?

Comment: You're asking the creator of JAXB what he prefers?  What do you expect him to say...

Comment: @StephenD - I am part of the group that created JAXB (JSR-222), and the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead :). JAXB is the default binding layer for JAX-WS so the two do work nicely together.

Comment: I had just asked a question about JAXB 10 minutes ago, but I found an answer you had posted that showed an example that was easy to follow.  Thanks!

Comment: @kodmanyagha - I have updated my answer with an example using the JAX-WS APIs so you have something to compare your approach with.

Comment: SOAPBody doesn't implement org.w3c.dom.Node, but javax.xml.soap.Node. The example has compile errors

Comment: @user831217 - `SOAPBody` does extend `org.w3c.dom.Node`:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html

Comment: You are right. Someone checked in very old version of SOAPBody into our project and I thought it is from JDK. Insane...